# Regex match everything between two string, spaning multiline

Tags: regex

How do I regex match everything that is between two strings? 
The things between two strings span several lines and can contain all html characters too.

For example:

```
<p>something</p>

<!-- OPTIONAL -->

<p class="sdf"> some text</p>
<p> some other text</p>

<!-- OPTIONAL END -->

<p>The end</p>
```

I want to strip the whole optional part off. but the greedy any character match isn't doing what I wanted.. the pattern I'm using is

- `<!-- OPTIONAL -->.*<!-- OPTIONAL END -->`
- `<!-- OPTIONAL -->(.*)<!-- OPTIONAL END -->`
- `<!-- OPTIONAL -->(.*)\s+<!-- OPTIONAL END -->`
- `(?=<!-- OPTIONAL -->)(.*)\s+<!-- OPTIONAL END -->`

All of them match the first optional tag, if only the first part is given, but doesn't do well with complete lines.

Here's an example: http://regexr.com?352bk

Thanks

Comment: You should not use a regex.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/34397

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @SLaks do XML parsers take HTML comments into account?

Comment: @rednaw: 1) Yes; XML uses the same comment syntax.  2) http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: @SLaks how would you strip the optional part out and return every thing else?

Comment: @rednaw, I'm using C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the dotall checkbox in RegExr :)

Without the dotall flag (the `s` in `/regex/s`), a dot (`.`) won't match carriage returns.

You should use [`.*?`](http://regexr.com?352c3) instead of [`.*`](http://regexr.com?352c6) to lazy match the optional content (see the `PLEASE DO NOT MATCH!` sentence in the examples).

Comment: Aah! what is dotall, and what does it do, please?

Comment: @LocustHorde By default the wildchard character in regex (`.`) doesn't match newline characters, meaning that the regex stops searching at the end of the line. By enabling dotall the `.` will also include the newline characters in its match.

Answer (score 8):

To make a regex ungreedy, use a `?` after the `*`:

```
<!-- OPTIONAL -->(.*?)<!-- OPTIONAL END -->
```

Does this help you?

Also depending on your programming language you use, you have modifiers that will make your regex dot (`.`) match newlines too. For PHP you have the `s` (dotall) modifier for example:

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Multiline isn't what the OP needs, but the dotall one. Multiline will make the `^$` anchors match multiple lines instead of a single one.

Comment: Good one, modified my answer

Answer (score 5):

playing with your example I think I found the answer, check this in your code:

```html
<!-- OPTIONAL -->[\w\W]*<!-- OPTIONAL END -->
```

I'll hope this help

Comment: I added "?" to the end to make less greedy: ```[\w\W]*?```

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "dotall" option so that the . in regex will match newline characters and work across multiple lines. There are various ways to do this depending on your implementation of regex, check the manual for your implementation.