# How to match all text between two strings multiline

Tags: regex

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16840126/1261657):

i.e. assuming you have a text like:

```
<p>something</p>

<!-- OPTIONAL -->

<p class="sdf"> some text</p>
<p> some other text</p>

<!-- OPTIONAL END -->

<p>The end</p>
```

What is the regex that would match:

```
<p class="sdf"> some text</p>
<p> some other text</p>
```

I've setup a [live test here](http://regexr.com/391sc) using:

```
<!-- OPTIONAL -->(.*?)<!-- OPTIONAL END -->
```

but it's not matching correctly. Also the accepted answer on the page didn't work for me. What am I missing?

Comment: the required `/s` modified is [not available in JavaScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your post so we can see the actual regex you used, and I disabled syntax highlighting on that part to reduce confusion.  I don't know why you had backslashes before the opening angle brackets (`\<`), but they weren't doing anything useful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well unfortunately, [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) is dependent on the JS RegExp implementation, which does not support the option to enable the *flag/modifier* that you need.

You are looking for the `s` (*DotAll*) modifier **forcing** the dot `.` to match newline sequences.

- [**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iN6pX6) on [regular expressions 101](http://regex101.com/#)

If you are using JavaScript, you can use this workaround:

```
/<!-- OPTIONAL -->([\S\s]*?)<!-- OPTIONAL END -->/
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the exact opposite of what I want, i.e. to remove the text in the middle. Is there a way I could reverse the regex? Great site btw.

Comment: Just place capturing groups around what you want. `(<!-- OPTIONAL -->).*?(<!-- OPTIONAL END -->)`

Comment: How might it be possible to grab *just* what's in between? I'd like to keep the identifiers (optional and optional end).